# How to add a constraint to a table using a partial index?

Tags: postgresql, index, constraint, postgresql-9.6, alter-table

I have a simple table:

```
create table item (
  lan      text not null,
  disabled date
);
```

My aim is to ensure uniqueness for the `lan` column over all rows, where `disabled` is `null`.

I created a partial index:

```
create unique index lan_idx on item (lan) where disabled is not null;
```

Now I tried to add the index to the table, but I am struggling with the syntax. (I took the code from [this](https://medium.com/flatiron-engineering/uniqueness-in-postgresql-constraints-versus-indexes-4cf957a472fd) tutorial)

```
alter table item add constraint lan_idx using index lan_idx;
```

This throws an syntax error before "using".

I also tried the following:

```
alter table item add constraint lan_idx unique using index lan_idx;
```

But this throws the error, that a unique constraint can not be created with a partial index.

Can anybody tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: You can't define a unique constraint with a partial index. But why do you want to do that? The unique index already gives you that behaviour.

Comment: `lan` should be unique only for those rows, where `disabled` is null.

Comment: Which your unique index already enforces - so why do you want an additional constraint?

Comment: I do not need to create a constraint? The creation of the index is enough?

Comment: Yes, the index is enough

Comment: Thanks. I misunderstood the tutorial I have read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't define a unique (or primary key) constraint based on a partial index.

However, to enforce uniqueness of the `lan` column for all non-deleted rows, the partial unique index you already have is enough.

There is no need to add a constraint.